# Change select menu value using click function

Tags: jquery

I am changing a select menu value using click function, It is changing a value. But I have also attached a change event with the select menu but it is not executing if we change select menu value from outside. The problem can be fixed by using `$('select').change()` that will trigger the change event but why we need to do this because we are already changed a value of select menu then change function should fired.

```
$('select').change(function(){
alert(0)
})

$('a').click(function(){
$('select').val(1)
})
```

Comment: fire a change event when you have changed value then... $("select").change(); When you change it through code, it's not like if it was a change event... maybe add your "change event" function on the value could work

Answer (score 0):

That's the way `.change()` works.
If you want it to fire after invoking `.val()`, you need to call it explicitly:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    alert(0);
});

$('a').click(function() {
    $('select').val(1).change();
});
```